# How to draw thousands of Sprites with different transparency?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, firemonkey

Hi I'm using Firemonkey because of it's cross platform capabilities. I want to render a particle system. Now I'm using a TMesh which works well enough to display the particles fast. Each particle is represented in the mesh via a two textured triangles. Using different texture coordinates I can show many different particle types with the same mesh. The problem is, that every particle can have its own transparency/opacity. With my current approach I cannot set the tranparency individually for each triangle (or even vertex). What can I do?

I realized that there are some other properties in TMesh.Data.VertexBuffer, like Diffuse or other sets of textures (TexCoord1-3), but these properties are not used (not even initalized) in TMesh. It also seems not easy to simply change this behavior by inheriting from TMesh. It seems one have to inherit from a lower level control to initialize the VertextBuffer with more properties. Before I try that, I'd like to ask if it would be possible to control the transparency of a triangle with that. E.g. can I set a transparent color (Diffuse) or use a transparent texture (TextCoor1)? Or is there a better way to draw the particles in Firemonkey.

Comment: "can I set a transparent color ... or use a transparent texture "... Why don't you just try it? Then come back and tell us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I admit that I don't know much about that particular framework, but you shouldn't be able to change transparency via vertex points in a 3D model. The points are usually x,y,z coordinates. Now, the vertex points would have an effect on how the sprites are lighted if you are using a lighting system. You can also use the vertex information to apply different transparency effects

Now, there's probably a dozen different ways to do this. Usually you have a texture with different degrees of alpha values that can be set at runtime. Graphics APIs usually have some filtering function that can quickly apply values to sprites/textures, and a good one will use your graphics chip if available.

If you can use an effect, it's usually better since the nuclear way is to make a bunch of different copies of a sprite and then apply effects to them individually. If you are using Gouraud Shading, then it gets easier since Gouraud uses code to fill in texture information.

Now, are you using light particles? Some graphics APIs actually have code that makes light particles.

Edit: I just remembered Vertex Shaders, which could.